# CLNDR.js & Underscore.js templating issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using the CLNDR.js plugin to create a nice mini calendar. I need to be able to access a value in an `event` function inside a `day` function. Let me try and explain below:

This is my JS code that populates the calendar. You'll see inside my JSON that I'm trying to add a `class: 'bank-holiday'` to the array of properties.

```
<script>
    var clndr = {};

    $( function() {

        var currentMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');
        var nextMonth    = moment().add(1,'month').format('YYYY-MM');

        var events = [
            <?php
            //Loop bank holiday dates from gov.uk website
            $events = json_decode($englandAndWalesEvents);
            foreach($events as $event){
                echo "{ date: '".$event->date."', title: '".$event->title."', url: 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays', class: 'bank-holiday' },";
            }
            ?>
        ];

        $('#mini-clndr').clndr({
            template: $('#mini-clndr-template').html(),
            weekOffset: 1,
            events: events,
            clickEvents: {
                click: function(target) {
                    if(target.events.length) {
                        var daysContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.days-container');
                        daysContainer.toggleClass('show-events', true);
                        $('#mini-clndr').find('.x-button').click( function() {
                            daysContainer.toggleClass('show-events', false);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            adjacentDaysChangeMonth: true,
            forceSixRows: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is my underscore.js template that populates my calendar:

```
<div class="days-container">
    <div class="days">
        <div class="headers">
            <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %><div class="day-header"><%= day %></div><% }); %>
        </div>
        <% _.each(days, function(day) { %><div class="<%= event.class %> <%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div><% }); %>
    </div>
    <div class="events">
        <div class="headers">
            <div class="x-button">x</div>
            <div class="event-header">EVENTS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="events-list">
            <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
            <div class="event">
                <a target="blank" href="<%= event.url %>"><%= moment(event.date).format('MMMM Do') %>: <%= event.title %></a>
            </div>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see in those code that I'm trying to utilise the `event.class` inside the `day` function. Is there a way to do this? You can see in the above code that the `event` function is being used to show `event.url` `event.title` etc.

`<% _.each(days, function(day) { %><div class="<%= event.class %> <%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div><% }); %>`

Thanks in advance for any help with this,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to loop through the days variable, and then there is an events key. Using this you can access the classes.

```
<%
    var classes = '';
    if( day.events.length ){
        for( var i = 0; i < day.events.length; i++ ){
            classes += ' ' + day.events[i].class;
        }
    }
%>


<div class="<%= day.classes %><%= classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change underscore.js delimiters, as it says it their site:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an escape regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML-escaped, and an
>   evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js-style
>   templating:
>
> ```
> _.templateSettings = {
>   interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
> };
>
> var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
> template({name: "Mustache"});
> => "Hello Mustache!"
> ```

Source: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Not sure this is the right thing to use? The data is already being loaded inside the `event` function further down the page. There's no issue with the delimiters, I just want to use a different functions properties inside another?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question, then, but I still don't understand the issue. Maybe you want to loop-load (loading A using B, but you need A to load B)?

Comment: In the code you can see that i've used `event.*` and `day.*` properties to display data. I need to use `event.class` inside the `day` template